# Oracle paging query performance

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle and I've noticed that pagination queries take the format.

```
select * 
from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
         a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
       from
         ( your_query_goes_here with filter and order by ) a 
       where
         ROWNUM <= :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where
  rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Why is there an extra outer select to split the min and max rownum where clause? Would this be just as performant and correct?

```
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */
  *
from 
  ( your_query_goes_here with filter and order by )
where
  ROWNUM between :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH and :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH
```

Shouldn't ROWNUM be already be correct since the inner query filters and orders the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the second query won't work.  It will always return 0 rows if `:MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH` is greater than 1.

Conceptually, if you have a query like

```
select * /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  from ( your_query_goes_here with filter and order by )
  where ROWNUM between :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH and :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH
```

where `:MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH` is 11 and `:MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH` is 20, Oracle would fetch the first row, give it a `rownum` of 1, then discard it because it didn't satisfy the predicate.  It would then fetch the second row from the inner query, give it a `rownum` of 1 (since no rows have been successfully returned yet), then discard it because it didn't satisfy the predicate.  That would repeat until every row had been fetched, assigned a `rownum` of 1, and discarded.  So the query would return 0 rows.

The extra layer of nesting ensures that the outer query with `rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH` sees rows with `rnum` values between 1 and `:MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH` and that the full query returns the expected set of rows.

If you're using 12.1 or later, you can use the `OFFSET ... FETCH` syntax as well

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 ORDER BY some_column
 OFFSET n ROWS
  FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have read that doc I linked to more closely. I see that it explains that ROWNUM is only assigned *after* the predicate phase so having a ROWNUM > X clause isn't very useful as an inclusion filter.